# The HTML box containing an SVG image does not match the Aspect Ratio of the image

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, svg

I'm trying to scale an SVG image to fit within its container using `preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid meet"`, which is the default, but I'm specifying it anyway for clarity.  With the CSS and SVG specified below, the scaling works like I want in Chrome.  However, in IE and Firefox the problem is that the polygon is scaling with a preserved aspect ratio, but the background is not.  The background is still filling the entire container, regardless of the aspect ratio of the container.  In the JSFiddle or code below, the background of the container should be green and the background of the image should be gray, with the gray portion being a square that circumscribes all four corners of the blue polygon, because the blue polygon is the same height and width as the square `viewBox`.

In other words, if the container's height > width, I want to see green above and below the gray/blue SVG image, and if the container's width > height, I want to see green on each side of the gray/blue SVG image.

Any ideas how I can make it look the way I want in all SVG-capable browsers?

http://jsfiddle.net/sJYEa/

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<style>

html, body{
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
}

#container {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0; bottom: 0; left: 0; right: 0;
    width: 80%;
    height: 80%;
    margin: auto;
    border: 5px solid black;
    background-color: green;
}

#testSVG{
    position: absolute;
    top: 0; bottom: 0; left: 0; right: 0;
    max-width: 100%;
    max-height: 100%;
    margin: auto;
    background-color: gray;
}

</style>
<title>Scratch Pad</title>
</head>
<body>

<div id="container">
    <svg
       xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
       version="1.1"
       id="testSVG"
       viewBox="0 0 300 300"
       preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid meet"
       width="5000"
       height="5000">
        <polygon points="150,0 300,150 150,300 0,150" style="fill:blue;" />
    </svg>
<!--
    <img id="testSVG" src="test.svg"/>
-->
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

I'll try to anticipate some questions people might have:

**Q:** Why do you want to do this with CSS instead of just changing the SVG drawing?

**A:** I'm planning to style not only the background, but also the borders with `border-radius`, maybe shadows, maybe a background texture, and change them dynamically using the `:hover`, `:focus`, `:active` pseudo-classes, which are all things I know how to do in CSS, but don't know how to do in SVG.  Also, I'll have to have a PNG fallback for old browsers and if I make the background, borders, etc. part of the image itself, that means I'll need multiple versions of the PNG depending on which pseudo-classes are applied.  For these reasons, I'd prefer to use CSS borders and backgrounds instead of adding additional SVG elements.

**Q:** Why are you using absolute positioning to center the `#testSVG`?  Shouldn't `xMidYMid` take care of the positioning for you?

**A:** That's what I thought, too, but it didn't.  Without the absolute positioning and `margin: auto`, Chrome drew the image in the upper left corner of the container, and then exhibited buggy scaling when the container was resized.

**Q:** Did you find different behavior when you referenced the SVG image via an `<img>` tag instead of putting the SVG inline?

**A:** Yes.  When I referenced the SVG via an `<img>` tag, IE wouldn't preserve the aspect ratio of the image unless I used `width` and `height` attributes of `100%` in the `<svg>` element, but in that case, Chrome would only show the green background if the container's height > width, not if the container's width > height.  And in neither case would IE show the green background at all.

**Q:** Why are you using such large values for the `svg` element's `width` and `height` attributes?

**A:** With a specified `width` and `height`, browsers seem to be happy to scale DOWN the image to fill the container, but refuse to scale UP the image to fill the container.  (Isn't that what `meet` is for in the `preserveAspectRatio` attribute?!)  Without a specified `width` and `height` (i.e. using the default values of `100%`), Chrome exhibited different behavior for portrait vs. landscape, as described in the previous answer.  At least with the way I currently have it, it works exactly like I want in one browser....

**Q:** I think I can make it work like you want, but I need to wrap the image in an extra non-semantic element.  Is that ok?

**A:** Yes!  I'm on board with the drive for HTML that's simple and purely semantic, but pedantry should always have a lower priority than practicality and functionality.

So, again, any thoughts on how I can make it work like I want in other browsers?

Comment: AFAIK, it is not really defined how an HTML style property like background-color applies to an SVG object.  So it is not surprising that browsers don't agree with each other.  The `<rect width="100%" height="100%"/>` technique is the only cross-browser solution to your problem I think.

Comment: Fundamentally, it's not a question of how to apply the style properties, it's a question of how to calculate the dimensions of the box that contains the image.  This should be covered in the spec: http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visudet.html (sections 10.3.2, 10.4, 10.6.2, and 10.7).  Chrome chooses to honor the 'intrinsic aspect ratio' of the image when calculating the box dimensions, so it shrinks the box to the extent necessary to honor the max-width and max-height constraints and fit the aspect ratio.  IE and Firefox calculate the box dimensions ignoring the aspect ratio.

Comment: Perhaps it is a difference of opinion as to whether the SVG viewBox attribute constitutes an 'intrinsic ratio'.  I (and the Chrome developers, apparently) think it should.  However, I can see an argument that the 'preserveAspectRatio' attribute specifies behavior allowing the viewBox aspect ratio to be ignored.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't find any consistent way to do this with only CSS. I did, however, find a solution that works across browsers using SVG.

I added a `<rect/>` that fills the entire width and height behind your drawing. Then I used CSS to set that `<rect/>`'s `fill` to use the same color you assigned to the SVG element's `background-color`.

[My updated JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8HdWe/4/)

*Tested and working in **Google Chrome** v31.0.1650.57 (1650.57), **Safari** v7.0 (9537.71), and **Firefox** v23.0 (2313.7.30) on **OS X 10.9** (13A603)*

Comment: Thanks, Tyler.  If I have to add additional SVG elements to make it work, I will, so thanks for the idea.  However, I'd prefer to use CSS backgrounds instead, for the reasons specified in the first Q&A above (which I just augmented).  If nobody comes up with a solution that doesn't involve adding additional SVG elements, I'll accept your solution, but I want to give it a day or two first.

Comment: @Craig — Works for me. I'm also interested in any solutions that use pure CSS to accomplish this.